# insert only single item of the array to the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a array containing of 250 eight character code. I am trying to insert this array to the table tbl_coupon. This is code I tried which is inserting only 1 data to the database.

I couldnot figure out where I did mistake.

```
$db = new Connection();
$sql = $db->query('insert into tbl_coupon(code) values(:code)');
$db->beginTransaction();
try {
    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
        $db->bind(':code', $coupon);
    }
    $db->execute();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $db->cancelTransaction();
}
$db->endTransaction();
```

Comment: You need to paste the whole code of inserting in foreach loop.

Comment: The problem is here :

    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
        $db->bind(':code', $coupon);
    }
Your are executing after the loop, your should do an array

Comment: @Pupil ah thank you I got it. I have to move $db->execute() inside the loop

Answer (score 3):

Call `$db->execute();` inside the foreach loop. The `bind()` just "replaces" the placeholder, so it is 250 times replaced and only the last one is executed.

```
$db = new Connection();
$sql = $db->query('insert into tbl_coupon(code) values(:code)');
$db->beginTransaction();
try {
    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
        $db->bind(':code', $coupon);
        $db->execute();
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $db->cancelTransaction();
}
$db->endTransaction();
```

Answer (score 0):

**$db->execute();**

Place this line inside for loop. You are binding the values inside for loop, the values will be binded to the statement and replaced till the last element in the array.

Then after completion of for loop you are calling $db->execute(), this will store only the last value of your array to the table